# angularjs get correct format data from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read values from json through angular and display data on UI. I am unable to do that because the format which I get to UI is not an array. When I added to console and see the format it is little different. I tried to to play with "c" in console and unable to play with the object. Any hint in how can I display {{details}} on my page?

[image]

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, MyService) {

            $scope.details = MyService.getDetails();
            console.log($scope.details);

    });
    app.service('MyService', function ($http) {
        this.getDetails = function (x, y) {

            return $http.get("/Home/GetMyData")
                     .then(function (response) {
                         return response.data;
                     });
        }
    });


</script>

        public JsonResult GetMyData()
        {
            var details = GetDet();
            return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: What is inside the objects inside the array named "value" ? Properties? I mean, what are the properties inside those objects?

Comment: Yes I have required  data inside value

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with fill code?

Comment: @Kurkula can you post the json what you get , and what you want to display? also the necessary HTML part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyService.getDetails` returns a promise and thus the code below only shows the promise object

```
$scope.details = MyService.getDetails();
console.log($scope.details); // promise object
```

You need to do this to get the resolved values of `getDetails`:

```
MyService
    .getDetails()
    .then(function(details){
        $scope.details = details;
        console.log($scope.details); // your array
    });
```

I hope this helps!